# Google Sheet Access Token

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I am a bit confused on the Access token. I have written a PHP script which inserts the data I get from the POST request , I already have authorized the App and it does add the Row at the end of the Sheet.

My Question is how I refresh the token when it get implemented on the server, as it will add the POST data.

Here is the Code

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');  
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {

  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
$lead = array (
"first_name" => $_POST['name'],
"email" => $_POST['email']
);

$sid = "sheet id on which the row is added";

addRowToSpreadsheet($lead, $client , $sid);

} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/fb/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}






function addRowToSpreadsheet($ary_values = array(), $client , $sid) {

    $sheet_service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

    $fileId = $sid;

    $values = array();
    foreach( $ary_values AS $d ) {
        $cellData = new Google_Service_Sheets_CellData();
        $value = new Google_Service_Sheets_ExtendedValue();
        $value->setStringValue($d);
        $cellData->setUserEnteredValue($value);
        $values[] = $cellData;
    }
    // Build the RowData
    $rowData = new Google_Service_Sheets_RowData();
    $rowData->setValues($values);
    // Prepare the request
    $append_request = new Google_Service_Sheets_AppendCellsRequest();
    $append_request->setSheetId(0);
    $append_request->setRows($rowData);
    $append_request->setFields('userEnteredValue');
    // Set the request
    $request = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request();
    $request->setAppendCells($append_request);
    // Add the request to the requests array
    $requests = array();
    $requests[] = $request;
    // Prepare the update
    $batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(array(
        'requests' => $requests
    ));

    try {
        // Execute the request
        $response = $sheet_service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($fileId, $batchUpdateRequest);
        if( $response->valid() ) {
            // Success, the row has been added
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Something went wrong
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }

    return false;
}
?>
```

I have tried hosting the app on the server and it doesn't add a new row in the Sheet, I think this is a problem due to the Access Token

Please Help

Comment: Kindly, check, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635962/google-spreadsheet-app-script-to-refresh-the-access-token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a [PHP Quickstart for Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) which includes how to refresh tokens. Here's a snippet:

```
 // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
```

There's also a [Refreshing an access token (offline access)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) guide with regard to refresh tokens

> Access tokens periodically expire. You can refresh an access token
>   without prompting the user for permission (including when the user is
>   not present) if you requested offline access to the scopes associated
>   with the token.
>
> If you use a Google API Client Library, the client object refreshes
>   the access token as needed as long as you configure that object for
>   offline access. If you are not using a client library, you need to set
>   the access_type HTTP query parameter to offline when redirecting the
>   user to Google's OAuth 2.0 server. In that case, Google's
>   authorization server returns a refresh token when you exchange an
>   authorization code for an access token. Then, if the access token
>   expires (or at any other time), you can use a refresh token to obtain
>   a new access token.
>
> If your application needs offline access to a Google API, set the API
>   client's access type to offline:
>
> ```
> $client->setAccessType("offline");
> ```